# How to open an instance of another or of itself from the current page

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, viewmodel

I created WPF on the MVVM principle, but I can't make it possible to open another one from the current page.
[I followed this example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266044/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-view/1266479#1266479)

We need something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH1Lv.png)

It is also worth considering that a page instance should be created. (That is, so that you can open yourself from Page 2, but with a different name)

My failed attempt:

**Page 2 ViewModel**

```
public Page2ViewModel()
{
        ButtonCommand = new RelayCommand(o => LoadOtherView());
}

public string Title { get; set; } = "Page2";
public string Text { get; set; } = "Page two";

public ICommand ButtonCommand { get; set; }
   
private void MainButtonClick(object sender)
{
      //MainViewModel main = new MainViewModel();
      //main.SelectedPageViewModel = main.PageViewModels[0];
      //main.SelectedPageViewModel.Title = "да";
      //main.SelectedPageViewModel.Text = "Первая страница";
}

private void LoadOtherView()
{
       // Instead of interacting with a whole ViewModel, we just use the interface
       //_pageDisplay.ChangePageCommand.Execute(new ContactViewModel());

       _pageDisplay.ChangeViewModel(_listPageViewModels[0]);
}
```

**Interfaces**

```
namespace WpfMVVMCore.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPageDisplay
    {
        public IPageViewModel GetCurrentPage();
        public IList<IPageViewModel> ListPageViewModels();
        public void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel newPage);
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel**

```
public MainViewModel(IPageDisplay pageDisplay, IList<IPageViewModel> ListPageViewModels)
{
    _pageDisplay = pageDisplay;
    _pageViewModels = ListPageViewModels;
}
public IPageViewModel GetCurrentPage()
{
       return _selectedPageViewModel;
}

public void ChangeViewModel(IPageViewModel newPage)
{
       this.SelectedPageViewModel = newPage;
}

public IList<IPageViewModel> ListPageViewModels()
{
     return _pageViewModels;
}
```

** If the information provided by me is not enough for you, you can download this project (with my unsuccessful attempt  ):[download](https://mega.nz/file/IWRSlboR#Yfw6x5ss0oYHMapm3IEnQjsdmqAvAHe98r1IUlPQfpo)**

P.S. Please do not criticize me if it is not difficult for you. I'm new to MVVM. Better help :)

Comment: Why do the view models have two constructors with the one with dependencies not being used...? Neither `_pageDisplay` or `_listPageViewModel` is ever initialized in your example so this code can never work.

Comment: @mm8 can I get more details?

Comment: Do you want details about your own code...? From who?

Comment: @мм8 To be honest, I don't understand what the constructor should be. I don't understand how it should look like

Comment: But still you have define two in each view model...?

Comment: And not, not for everyone) But it still didn't help, I have a mistake: `System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Comment: @mm8 I left a link to the project so that there would be fewer questions to the code

Comment: Regarding the exception, please read my first comment again.

Comment: @мм8 I didn't understand how to do it. Please show an example